# Expected value of the infinite product of indepedent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

We assume that $Y_{n}$ are independent random variables and we let $Y_{n}$ have the values $\frac{3}{2}$or $\frac{1}{2}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. We let $X_{n}=Y_{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot Y_{n}$. I showed that $\lbrace X_{n} \rbrace$ is a martingale. However, I am also suppose to show that $\lbrace X_{n} \rbrace$ converges to $X=0$, a.s, and that $E(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}) \le \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}E(Y_{n})$.

This problem is from Patrick Billingsley's "Probability and Measure". The hint given was to let $S_{n}$ be the number of $k$ such that $1 \le k \le n$ and $Y_{k}=\frac{3}{2}$. Then $X_{n}=\frac{3^{S_{n}}}{2^{n}}$. Then we take logarithms and use the Strong Law of Large Numbers. I am having trouble completing this problem, even with the hint included.

Comment: Note that $X_n^{1/n}=3^{S_n/n}/2$ and $S_n/n\to1/2$ almost surely, hence $X_n^{1/n}\to\sqrt3/2$ almost surely, in particular, $X_n^{1/n}\leqslant.9$ for every $n$ large enough, almost surely. Can you conclude?

Comment: Thanks Did. I get $X_{n} \le (.9)^{n}$ which gives $X_{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I didn't use logarithms for this result and I'm still not sure how it all ties into the expectation inequality above.

Comment: @Did...I figured it out: We can use the following theorem: Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be a submartingale. If $K=\sup_{n}E(|X_{n}|)<\infty$ then $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ a.s. and $X$ is a random variable with $E(|X|) \le K$

Comment: Nice theorem, which is absolutely not needed to solve this exercise.